# How to use two csv files in one test, one csv for login multiple users and second csv is to each user should select each record separately

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is multiple users should login and after login each user should select the each record separately in application.

Comment: post what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

Define two **Thread groups** in your test plan. Under these two thread groups use different (Two) **CSV** files.

For Further Details, see [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)